# How to prevent nightcode running on windows 10 form modifying clojure code in unwanted ways

Tags: clojure, ide, editing

When using nightcode to write code such as this

```
(defn trick
  "Describe the kind of trick you will perform"
  ([name kind-of-trick]
   (str name " will perform a " kind-of-trick "! Watch and be amazed!"))
  ([name]
    (trick name "backflip")))
```

nightcode repeatedly moves the right square bracket to include one or more of the following code.  The third and fourth line of the above program becomes

```
  ([name kind-of-trick
     (str name " will perform a " kind-of-trick "! Watch and be amazed!")])
```

I delete the ] and place it back immediately after kind-of-trick, but nightcode undoes my edit and returns it to the code above.

This has occurred in several different programs written by least two of us.

Answer (score 1):

Nightcode uses a Parinfer-like editing mode by default that apparently [can't be disabled](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nightcode/comments/50trhr/disabling_parinfer/).

This Parinfer-like editing mode uses *indentation* to automatically match begin/end parentheses, square brackets, curly brackets, etc. This means you'll need to indent your code such that the indentation matches its expectations.

```
(defn trick
  "Describe the kind of trick you will perform"
  ([name kind-of-trick]
   (str name " will perform a " kind-of-trick "! Watch and be amazed!"))
  ([name]
   (trick name "backflip")))
```

For your multi-arity function definition, the opening parenthesis of each function body must align with the opening square bracket of the argument vector directly above. Just one character to the left or right will result in improperly placed parentheses.

Comment: It should be noted that this isn't specific to Nightcode. I use IntelliJ+Cursive, which uses ParInfer, and it's a bad time trying to code multi-arity functions. I've actually reduced how often I create multi-arity functions it's such a pain. You need to intent everything by a single space for it to work properly, which is awful for large functions. I'll more often opt for abusing var-args to get multi-arity behavior.

Comment: Yep, I use IntelliJ+Cursive too (and mostly with Parinfer) and there are some quirks. Unlike Nightcode, you can toggle Parinfer mode in Cursive: just click in the bottom-right toolbar where it says _Parinfer_ and select _Structural Off_.

Comment: Ya. I only turn it off when golfing though. I've found if you turn it off, write some code, then turn it back on, it automatically adjusts everything to match the indentation anyways. It's only worth turning off if you're shoving everything into one line in the end.